# Free web-based Test Case Management Software

Tags: testing

Does someone know a free web-based test case management software? I looked around in the internet and on some comparisons, but either they are expensive as hell or looking bad as hell ... (basic HTML tables).

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: Do you refer to test-case-manager (which test cases are available, what are their prerequisites, which feature do they cover) or test-execution-manager (which contain the results of test execution, historical data and logs) or both?

Comment: To Test-case managers. I want to create a set of test cases, let them run and see reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried for same but as u said no tool can fulfill requirements so i am using Test Point Metrics approach. It is best approach in any environment. By this approach not only we can do unit and integration testing but also validate the requirements. Time for writing Test Point Metrics is just after the Requirement understanding

A template of Test Point Metrics available here:

http://www.docstoc.com/docs/80205542/Test-Plan

And a comprehensive review on such tools available here:

http://www.opensourcetesting.org/testmgt.php

Comment: We finally ended up using Google Docs Spreadsheets. For each testsuite we create a sheet (a template) and for each  run we copy this tempate and give it a name like "UI TESTS, FF 3.6, MAC OS 10.6". Its super easy as everyone can collaborate and you even have basic access control. The only drawback is a lack of maintaineability, but it can be done, though ...